# Fast counting of nucleotide types in a large number of sequences

Tags: c++, count, character, fasta

First, a bit of background about my question.
I work as a bioinformatician, which means that I do informatics treatment to try to answer a biological question. In my problem, I have to manipulate a file called a FASTA file which looks like this :

```
>Header 1  
ATGACTGATCGNTGACTGACTGTAGCTAGC  
>Header 2  
ATGCATGCTAGCTGACTGATCGTAGCTAGC  
ATCGATCGTAGCT
```

So a FASTA file is basically just a header, preceded by a '>' character, then a sequence on one or multiple lines that is composed of nucleotides. Nucleotides are characters that can take 5 possible values : A, T, C, G or N.

The thing I would like to do is count the number of times each nucleotide type appears so if we consider this dummy FASTA file :

```
>Header 1  
ATTCGN
```

I should have, as a result :
`A:1 T:2 C:1 G:1 N:1`

Here is what I got so far :

```
ifstream sequence_file(input_file.c_str());
string line;
string sequence = "";
map<char, double> nucleotide_counts;

while(getline(sequence_file, line)) {
    if(line[0] != '>') {
        sequence += line;
    }
    else {
        nucleotide_counts['A'] = boost::count(sequence, 'A');
        nucleotide_counts['T'] = boost::count(sequence, 'T');
        nucleotide_counts['C'] = boost::count(sequence, 'C');
        nucleotide_counts['G'] = boost::count(sequence, 'G');
        nucleotide_counts['N'] = boost::count(sequence, 'N');
        sequence = "";
    }
}
```

So it reads the file line by line, if it encounters a '>' as the first character of the line, it knows that the sequence is complete and starts to count. Now the problem I'm facing is that I have millions of sequences with several billions of nucleotides in total. I can see that my method is not optimized because I call `boost::count` five times on the same sequence.

Other things I have tried :

- Parsing the sequence to increment a counter for each nucleotide types. I tried using a `map<char, double>` to map each nucleotide to a value but this was slower than the boost solution.
- Using the `std::count` of the algorithm library but this was too slow too.

I searched the internet for solutions but every solution I found was good if the number of sequences was low, which is not my case. Would you have any idea that could help me speed things up ?

**EDIT 1** :
I also tried this version but it was 2 times slower than the boost one :

```
ifstream sequence_file(input_file.c_str());
string line;
string sequence = "";
map<char, double> nucleotide_counts;

while(getline(sequence_file, line)) {
    if(line[0] != '>') {
        sequence += line;
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
           nucleotide_counts[sequence[i]]++;
        }
        sequence = "";
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2** : Thanks to everyone in this thread, I was able to obtain a speed up of about 30 times compared to the boost original solution. Here is the code :

```
#include <map> // std::array
#include <fstream> // std::ifstream
#include <string> // std::string  

void count_nucleotides(std::array<double, 26> &nucleotide_counts, std::string sequence) {
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sequence.size(); i++) {
        ++nucleotide_counts[sequence[i] - 'A'];
    }
}  

std::ifstream sequence_file(input_file.c_str());
std::string line;
std::string sequence = "";
std::array<double, 26> nucleotide_counts;

while(getline(sequence_file, line)) {
    if(line[0] != '>') {
        sequence += line;
    }
    else {
        count_nucleotides(nucleotide_counts, sequence);
        sequence = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know what boost::count does, but it seems as if you traverse the same string 5 times when one time would be suficient

Comment: just look at each character individually and increment the right counter.

Comment: Iterate over the sequence once, incrementing the mapped value for each neucleotide, but instead of using a `map` which has quite slow access, either use an `unordered_map` or use a `vector` with size 26, and realise that, for example `'C'-'A' == 2`. (Sure you would waste 19 unused spaces in the `vector`, but I bet it is pretty quick, and hardly a lot of memory to waste).

Comment: If the dataset is enormous, it might be faster to have an enum of all possible 4 character combinations, and compare 4 bytes at a time.

Comment: By the way, I notice you do not use `unordered_map`, and you use `.c_str()` when opening a file, which makes me wonder if you are using a very old version of C++. Do you know which version you are using?

Comment: @BoBTFish Thank you for your comment about the vector, I am trying to implement it as we speak. I don't really know which version of C++ this is, I am using g++ 4.9.2 if that means something.

Comment: For 'Edit 2' code: No need to build `sequence += line;` first, just count every sequence line separate. Better use `std::array<int, 256>` (or unsigned int): no need for double.. and sequence can be lowercase sometimes, or even other characters than ATCGN - then you can just use `++nucleotide_counts[sequence[i]];` and at the end add the counts for 'a' and 'A' etc, and/or check for other characters.

Comment: You could also try to avoid streaming, which can be slow. This would actually be a great candidate for memory mapping: just scan over the file (as an array) reading each byte only once - no need for scanning and copying each line into a buffer (getline()).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use a map if you want speed and can use an array. Also, [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) can use a custom delimiter (instead of `\n`).

```
ifstream sequence_file(input_file.c_str());
string sequence = "";
std::array<int, 26> nucleotide_counts;

// For one sequence
getline(sequence_file, sequence, '>');
for(auto&& c : sequence) {
    ++nucleotide_counts[c-'A'];
}

// nucleotide_counts['X'-'A'] contains the count of nucleotide X in the sequence
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2dcf6275b9dcba0b)

Answer (score 1):

If this is the main task you have to perform, you might have an interest in an awk solution. Various problems with FASTA files are very easily tackled with awk:

```
awk '/^>/ && c { for(i in a) if (i ~ /[A-Z]/) printf i":"a[i]" "; print "" ; delete a }
    /^>/ {print; c++; next}
    { for(i=1;i<=length($0);++i) a[substr($0,i,1)]++ }
    END{ for(i in a) if (i ~ /[A-Z]/) printf i":"a[i]" "; print "" }' fastafile
```

This outputs on your example:

```
>Header 1  
N:1 A:7 C:6 G:8 T:8 
>Header 2  
A:10 C:10 G:11 T:12
```

*note:* I am aware that this is not C++, but it is often useful to show other means to achieve the same goal.

---

**Benchmarks with awk:**

- testfile: http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.fa.gz
- unziped size: 2.3G
- total records: 5502947
- total lines:

**Script 0: *(runtime: too long)*** The first mentioned script is utterly slow. Use only on small files

**Script 1: *(runtime: 484.31 sec)*** This is an optimised version where we do a targetted count:

```
/^>/ && f { for(i in c) printf i":"c[i]" "; print "" ; delete c }
/^>/ {print; f++; next}
{   s=$0
    c["A"]+=gsub(/[aA]/,"",s)
    c["C"]+=gsub(/[cC]/,"",s)
    c["G"]+=gsub(/[gG]/,"",s)
    c["T"]+=gsub(/[tT]/,"",s)
    c["N"]+=gsub(/[nN]/,"",s)
}
END { for(i in c) printf i":"c[i]" "; print "" ; delete c }
```

---

**Update 2: *(runtime: 416.43 sec)*** Combine all the subsequences into a single sequence and count only ones:

```
function count() {
    c["A"]+=gsub(/[aA]/,"",s)
    c["C"]+=gsub(/[cC]/,"",s)
    c["G"]+=gsub(/[gG]/,"",s)
    c["T"]+=gsub(/[tT]/,"",s)
    c["N"]+=gsub(/[nN]/,"",s)
}
/^>/ && f { count(); for(i in c) printf i":"c[i]" "; print "" ; delete c; string=""}
/^>/ {print; f++; next}
{ string=string $0 }
END { count(); for(i in c) printf i":"c[i]" "; print "" }
```

**Update 3: *(runtime: 396.12 sec)*** Refine how awk finds its records and fields, and abuse this in a single go.

```
function count() {
    c["A"]+=gsub(/[aA]/,"",string)
    c["C"]+=gsub(/[cC]/,"",string)
    c["G"]+=gsub(/[gG]/,"",string)
    c["T"]+=gsub(/[tT]/,"",string)
    c["N"]+=gsub(/[nN]/,"",string)
}
BEGIN{RS="\n>"; FS="\n"}
{
  print $1
  string=substr($0,length($1)); count()
  for(i in c) printf i":"c[i]" "; print ""
  delete c; string=""
}
```

**Update 4: *(runtime: 259.69 sec)*** Update the regex search in `gsub`. This creates a worthy speedup:

```
function count() {
    n=length(string);
    gsub(/[aA]+/,"",string); m=length(string); c["A"]+=n-m; n=m
    gsub(/[cC]+/,"",string); m=length(string); c["C"]+=n-m; n=m
    gsub(/[gG]+/,"",string); m=length(string); c["G"]+=n-m; n=m
    gsub(/[tT]+/,"",string); m=length(string); c["T"]+=n-m; n=m
    gsub(/[nN]+/,"",string); m=length(string); c["N"]+=n-m; n=m
}
BEGIN{RS="\n>"; FS="\n"}
{
  print ">"$1
  string=substr($0,length($1)); count()
  for(i in c) printf i":"c[i]" "; print ""
  delete c; string=""
}
```

Comment: This is an interesting and neat solution, but do you have any comment on how well it performs? Is `awk` going to come close to a `C++` implementation?

Comment: @BoBTFish awk will be fast but surely not as fast as C++. Everything depends on the global task at hand and tradeoff. Do you have Gigabytes of data files you have to analyze and you have to do this for days and days ... then, yes it might be useful to write an optimized C++ program. If you have to do this only a few times, maybe a simple script language is good enough.

Comment: OP mentions *several billions of nucleotides*. That surely amounts to some gigabytes.

Comment: @Nelfeal "Several" GB, to be precise. ;)

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm runing a test now on http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/bigZips/hg38.fa.gz

Comment: @MaxLanghof I don't know, the files might be compressed.

Comment: @BoBTFish seems i get it in a bit over 5 minutes. I'm very convinced that C++ can do this faster.

Comment: @BoBTFish and now below 5 minutes

Comment: @Nelfeal I would be interested to see a benchmark with your final C++, just out of curiousity.

Comment: @kvantour You're free to do it. I included a complete example in my answer.

Comment: @Nelfeal C++ is about 3 times faster. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

In order of importance:

1. Good code for this task will 100% be **I/O-bound**. Your processor can count characters much faster than your disk can pump them to the CPU. Thus, the first question to me is: What is the throughput of your storage medium? What are your ideal RAM and cache throughputs? Those are the upper limits. If you've hit them, there's not much point in looking at your code further. It's possible that your boost solution is there already.
2. `std::map` lookups are relatively expensive. Yes, it's `O(log(N))`, but your `N=5` is small and constant, so this tells you nothing. For 5 values, the map will have to chase about three pointers for every lookup (not to mention how impossible this is for the branch predictor). Your `count` solution has 5 map lookups and 5 traversals of each string, whereas your manual solution has a map lookup *for every nucleotide* (but only one traversal of the string).

   Serious suggestion: Use a **local variable for each counter**. Those will almost surely get placed in CPU registers and are therefore essentially free. You won't ever pollute your cache with the counters that way, unlike `map`, `unordered_map`, `vector` etc.
   Replacing abstraction by repetition like this is usually not a good idea, but in this case, it's pretty inconceivable that you'll ever need significantly more counters, so scalability is not an issue.
3. Consider **`std::string_view`** (which would require a different method of reading the file) to **avoid creating copies** of the data. You load the entire data into memory from disk and then, for each sequence, you copy it. That's not really necessary and (depending on how smart your compiler is) can bog you down. Especially since you keep appending to the string until the next header (which is more unnecessary copying - you could just count after every line).
4. If, for some reason, you are not hitting the theoretical throughputs, consider multithreading and/or vectorization. But I can't imagine this would be necessary.

By the way, `boost::count` is a thin wrapper around `std::count` at least [in this version](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/boost/range/algorithm/count.hpp).

I think you did the right thing here though: Writing good and readable code, then identifying it as performance bottleneck and checking if you can make it run faster (potentially by making it slightly more ugly).

Comment: Thank you for these precious insights, I have edited my post to show the solution I came up with the help of everyone in this thread. As we speak, I am trying to implement your point 3.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's so slow is that you have indirect accesses all the time or 5 scans of the same string.

You don't need a map, use 5 integers, and increment them separately. Then it should be faster than the `boost::count` version because you don't traverse the string 5 times, and it will be faster than the `map` or the `unordered_map` increments because you won't have n indirect accesses.

so use something like:

```
switch(char)
{
case 'A':
    ++a;
    break;
case 'G':
    ++g;
    break;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Like people in comments suggested, try sth like that

```
enum eNucleotide {
    NucleotideA = 0,
    NucleotideT,
    NucleotideC,
    NucleotideG,
    NucleotideN,
    Size,
};

void countSequence(std::string line)
{
    long nucleotide_counts[eNucleotide::Size] = { 0 };

    if(line[0] != '>') {
        for(int i = 0; i < line.size(); ++i) 
        {
           switch (line[i])
           {
               case 'A':
                   ++nucleotide_counts[NucleotideA];
                   break;
               case 'T':
                   ++nucleotide_counts[NucleotideT];
                   break;                   
               case 'C':
                   ++nucleotide_counts[NucleotideC];
                   break;                   
               case 'G':
                   ++nucleotide_counts[NucleotideC];
                   break;                   
               case 'N':
                   ++nucleotide_counts[NucleotideN];
                   break;                   
               default : 
                   /// error condition
                   break;
           }     
        }

    /// print results
    std::cout << "A: " << nucleotide_counts[NucleotideA];
    std::cout << "T: " << nucleotide_counts[NucleotideT];
    std::cout << "C: " << nucleotide_counts[NucleotideC];
    std::cout << "G: " << nucleotide_counts[NucleotideG];
    std::cout << "N: " << nucleotide_counts[NucleotideN] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and call this function for every line content.(Didn't tested code.)